# Java Waiting for a Timer until it's finished

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread which does some work. And there is a javax.swing.Timer to wait for a couple of Seconds and update a progressbar.

Now my problem is, that i want to perform further code like

```
jTextArea1.append("continue ..\n");
```

when the Timer has finished. The whole Code is running inside a Thread.
Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

```
jTextArea1.append(String.format("%d seconds to wait ..\n", wait));
System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");

waiting = true;
final Timer timer = new Timer(wait*1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1);
        if (jProgressBar1.getValue() == 100) {
            synchronized (this) {
                waiting = false;
                this.notify();
            }
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
synchronized (timer) {
    timer.start();
    while(waiting)  
        timer.wait();
}
System.out.println(waiting + " " + new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
jTextArea1.append("continue...\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if (jProgressBar1.getValue() == 100) {
```

You already have code **inside** your timer that understands that the timer should "end" now.

So, what I would do: create a method like `onTimerEnd()` - and implement *all** the things you want to happen when that timer ends *inside* that method - and then invoke that method.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But my problem is, that I wan't to do some stuff then wait for example 62 seconds and display a progress bar and then start from the beginning? How would I implement that?